# node.js fs.existsSync always false

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, fs

I have a file on this path:
`~/Downloads/flightlog_2017-71-19_19747.txt`

But when i try to write or check if it exist:

`fs.existsSync('~/Downloads/flightlog_2017-71-19_19747.txt')`

It always return `false`

If I do in terminal:

`$ nano ~/Downloads/flightlog_2017-71-19_19747.txt`

This works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think using ~ to reference a users' Home directory is supported in Node. As there is no equivalent command in Windows.

You can follow this thread for the complete discussion.
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/684

For the Time being you can use [untildify](https://github.com/sindresorhus/untildify) npm package for your needs.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace `~` with dynamically fetched `homedir` using `const homedir = require('os').homedir();`.

So instead of:

`fs.existsSync('~/Downloads/flightlog_2017-71-19_19747.txt')`

You could do something like:

```
const homedir = require('os').homedir();
fs.existsSync(homedir + '/Downloads/flightlog_2017-71-19_19747.txt')
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

`~` is special to the shell (terminal process), expanding to the current home directory, but it is **not** special otherwise. You'll need to use an absolute path, or a relative path (relative to the process).

For instance, assuming `~` maps to `/home/arti`:

```
fs.existsSync('/home/arti/Downloads/flightlog_2017-71-19_19747.txt')
```

Or if you're running the process in `~/example`, then this relative path would work:

```
fs.existsSync('../Downloads/flightlog_2017-71-19_19747.txt')
```